# Are there curves of genus 2 with real multiplication by a non-maximal order?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties

Let us work over $\mathbb{C}$ for the moment.

Assume we are given a real quadratic field $K$ with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$.

$\mathbf{Question:}$ Is there a smooth projective curve $C$ of genus $g=2$ such that $End(Jac(C))$ is a non-maximal order in $K$, that is $End(Jac(C))=\mathcal{O}_{K,f}=\mathbb{Z}+f\mathcal{O}_K$ for some $f>1$, especially $\neq \mathcal{O}_K$? If yes can we find such a curve for every $K$ and every $f>1$?

Comment: It is sufficient to find a principally polarized abelian variety with that endomorphism algebra, as then it would automatically be a Jacobian, as it is not a product of two elliptic curves. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86549/schottky-locus-in-genus-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for every quadratic ring of discriminant $f^2 D$ (where $D$ is the discriminant of $K$ in your notation), there's a Humbert surface's worth of such Jacobians. See David Gruenewald's thesis 
 (available at http://echidna.maths.usyd.edu.au/~davidg/thesis.pdf) and the references there for calculations of Humbert surfaces. The double cover, which is the Hilbert modular surface, can also be computed in various ways. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3527 for a method using elliptic K3 surfaces (for fundamental discriminants) and https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2849 for non-fundamental discriminants if K is replaced by the disc 1 quadratic algebra $\mathbf{Q} \oplus \mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: It seems that the link in the post is dead and the new link is http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/davidg/thesis.pdf ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20181008112432/http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/davidg/thesis.pdf)).